# JIRA - Outgoing EMail Queue Issue?

Tags: jira, jira-agile

JIRA Doesn't send a Issue mail and all mails are moved to error mail queue and none of the receiptent receive any mails.and we made the refresh mail queue to 60 secs for resending error mails in queue but no luck.

Please kindly anyone help on this Issue.

Comment: Take a look at your emailer setup, see if Jira is able to connect to the emailing server

Comment: I have tested the connection...Its working fine...And only few mails are in the error queues.